# Composer dependency on local repository

Tags: composer-php

I want to set up a main project depending on other local projects. That works actually fine. But when a dependency has a dependency by itself, `composer update` exists with an error.

**Set up:**

I have three packages.

```
/home/programming/git
    vendor.main
    vendor.depA
    vendor.depB
```

`vendor/main` depends on `vendor.depA` which in turn depends on `vendor.depB`.

**What works**

The `vendor/main` composer.json defines a dependency on `vendor.depA`:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/main",
    "description": "main",
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "/home/user/programming/git/vendor.depA/" },
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "/home/user/programming/git/vendor.depB/" }
    ],
    "require": {
        "vendor/depA": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

And `vendor.depA` has no other dependency:

```
{
        "description": ". . .",
        "name": "vendor/depA"
}
```

`composer update` works as expected and installs `vendor/depA`.

**What doesn't work**

If `vendor.depA` defines a dependency on `vendor/depB` `composer update` fails:

```
{
        "description": ". . .",
        "name": "vendor/depA",
        "require": {
                "vendor/depB": "dev-master"
        }
}
```

Adding the repository to the `vendor.depA`'s composer.json doesn't help.

`composer update` runs through, if I add the dependency to `vendor.main`'s composer.json (so, there is no typo, or another problem with `vendor/depB`, etc), but that doesn't really help, since depA should have the dependency.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: The error message

```
 ~/composer.phar update Loading composer repositories with package
 information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)             
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
 packages.

   Problem 1
     - vendor/depA dev-master requires vendor/depB dev-master -> no matching package found.
     - vendor/depA dev-master requires vendor/depB dev-master -> no matching package found.
     - Installation request for vendor/depA dev-master -> satisfiable by vendor/depA[dev-master].

 Potential causes:
  - A typo in the package name
  - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see
 <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more
 details.
  - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

 Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for
 further common problems.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not working with "dev-master". In you case that makes no sense then "dev-master" is always the latest version of your master branch. So you should tag a commit and work with tags and set your requirement depending on a tag number.

Here is an example how you can define a package if you really want to define it in your composer file.

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
      "name": "vendor/yourpackage",
      "version": "v1.0.0",
      "source": {
        "url": "git@your.gitserver.com:vendor/project.git",
        "type": "git",
        "reference": "dd6ed3c8"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Then you have created a package with the specified version number "1.0.0" and that package is set to a git commit.